# Access a class field from static method

Tags: php, oop, static-methods

For example, I have a class

```
class MyClass
{
    public $something = 'base';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $something = 'construct';
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $something = 'destruct';
    }

    public static doSomething()
    {
        $return = new MyClass;
        echo $return->something;
    }
}
```

So, my question is this... Will running the static method without instantiating the object run the constructor? If I had, for example, database connection information in the constructor, could I run a static method that returns a query withing explicitly instantiating the class?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the construction will be called in your example. Since you already have the code, I guess it would be easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute MyClass::doSomething(), it will create object of MyClass and, of course, its constructor will be called. Why not to run it and see the result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm lacking PHP knowledge, but compared to other OO languages it will of course run the constructor, because you tell the static method to create a new instance of MyClass.

The same would apply if you called a new SomeOtherType. The code itself doesn't care if it's inside a static/public/private method, as long as new is there, the constructor is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I did not ask the question correctly, but the answer is that as long as the object is instantiated, even within a static method, the constructor will run. The output would be whatever is in the constructor as the deconstructor does not fire until after the last call to the class.

Sorry for the confusion in the question.